# What happened to my comments on Google+?

Tags: google-plus, comments

I don't know whether this question has been asked earlier, the problem seems pretty unique to me. I was commenting on this hotly debated post, posted some 30-40 comments, then all of a sudden I realise no one is able to see comments beyond the 10-12th comment. Can someone enlighten me as to what happened?

[This](https://plus.google.com/100158528827446960868/posts/2Puxy7tsDys) is the post in question; as you can see a number of questions have been directed at me, and I have responded (I can see my comments) but no one else can. (I confirmed this using a friend's account).

Comment: I see the comments fine here

Comment: From here, "You don't see these wars happening..." is your last comment. Have you posted more after that?